# Commutation of the Hamiltonian with the generator of boost

Tags: special-relativity, angular-momentum, conservation-laws, hamiltonian-formalism, poisson-brackets

Consider the Hamiltonian $H = (\textbf{P}^2+m^2)^{1/2}$ the generators of rotation and and boost given by $$M^{0i} = tP^i-x^iH \\ M^{ij} = x^iP^j-x^jP^i$$ where $x^i$ and $P^j$ satisfy $\{x^i, P^j\} = \delta^{ij}$. From the above, we see that $$\{M^{0i}, H\} = P^i$$ However, explicit time derivative of $M^{0i}$ leads to $$\frac{d}{dt}M^{0i} = P^i-\dot{x}^i H$$ And since $\dot{x}^i = \{x^i, H\} = P^i/H$, we have $$\frac{d}{dt}M^{0i}= 0$$Why is it that $\frac{d}{dt}M^{0i}\neq \{H, M^{0i}\}$? Can someone please explain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ...From the above, we see that $$\{M^{0i}, H\} = P^i$$

No, you should have:
$$
\{M^{0i}, H\} = -P^i
$$

> ...Why is it that $\frac{d}{dt}M^{0i}\neq \{H, M^{0i}\}$? Can someone please explain?

It's because your operator has *explicit* time dependent, which you have neglected.

For any function $f(x,P; t)$ [we have](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_bracket):
$$
\frac{df}{dt} = \left\{f,H\right\} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}
$$
so
$$
\frac{dM^{0i}}{dt} = \left\{M^{0i},H\right\} + \frac{\partial M^{0i}}{\partial t}
$$
$$
=-P^i + P^i = 0
$$